# Circular face issue that I can't figure out how to remove?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I was trying to make a flower stem a with multiple leaves coming out along the stem. I created several edge loops the length of the cylinder, then made edge loops on either side of the first one so I could extrude the stem out. As I extruded I rotated, scaled, and re-positioned the extrusion. Afterwards I selected the main stem and scaled only it down on the X and Y axis.
But it seemed to create a disconnect from the first extrusion along the stem. There was a noticeable gap between all but one edge of the extrusion and the rest of the stem. I ended up deleting the faces of the first extrusion then bridging the vertices of the second with the stem.

I then noticed some very visible circular face... deformities around the edge loops connected to the extrusion. They were not present at the time of my noticing the first extrusion's gap issue.

I've tried scaling, rotating, and extruding various edges and the faces themselves but nothing seems to remove them. They're also very visible in the render preview.

I don't know how to get rid of this circular stuff

[image]

Comment: In Edit Mode select all and W > Remove Doubles.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Thanks Luke, worked perfectly. Also thanks Ray, I'll definitely use image uploading from now on.